# How to display a composite on the top of another composite which contains a table viewer?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

In the `createControl(parent)` method of the `Wizard` Page, the code is as below-

```
    top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    top.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    setControl(top);
    setPageComplete(false);
    createViewer(top);
```

I want to add a `row` above the composite denoted by `top`.

It doesn't allows me. If I add it, the `composite` denoted by `top` gets lost.

The below is rendered for the top composite -

[image]

The moment I place the below code before the `top` composite, the `top` composite gets lost -

```
    upper = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    upper.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    setControl(upper);
    Label label = new Label(page, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Some text to disply");
```

Please suggest on how to achieve the same.

---

The below is the `createControl` snippet in my case. It breaks the scrolling and size of the table viewer if add a row.

```
@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {

    /*top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    top.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    setControl(top);*/
    setPageComplete(false);

    top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    top.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    setControl(top);

    Label label = new Label(top, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("Some text to disply");
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));


    createViewer(top);
}

private void createViewer(Composite parent) {

    tableLayout = new TableColumnLayout();

    // A separate composite containing just the table viewer is required
    Composite tableComp = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    tableComp.setLayout(tableLayout);
    viewer = new TableViewer(tableComp, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
    createColumns(parent, viewer);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());

    // Layout the viewer
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
}

public TableViewer getViewer() {
    return viewer;
}
```

[image]

---

```
// This will create the columns for the table
    private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer) {
        String[] titles = { "Node Status", "Node Type", "Node Name" };
        int[] bounds = { 100, 100, 100 };
        Image HEADER = CommonUtility.HEADER;

        TableViewerColumn col = null;

        // First column is for type
        col = createTableViewerColumn(HEADER, titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
        col.setLabelProvider(new CentredImageCellLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel model = (GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel) element;
                if (model.isNew()) {
                    return CommonUtility.CHECKED;
                } else {
                    return CommonUtility.UNCHECKED;
                } 
            }
        });
        // Weight for column
        tableLayout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(50));

        // now the newly created
        col = createTableViewerColumn(HEADER, titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
        col.setLabelProvider(new CentredImageCellLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel model = (GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel) element;
                if ("ns_flow".equals(model.getIcon())) {
                    return CommonUtility.FLOW_SERVICE;
                } 
                if ("ns_open_interface".equals(model.getIcon())) {
                    return CommonUtility.FOLDER;
                } 
                if ("ns_record".equals(model.getIcon())) {
                    return CommonUtility.DOCUMENT_TYPE;
                } 
                if ("ns_package".equals(model.getIcon())) {
                    return CommonUtility.PACKAGE;
                } 
                if("RestResource".equals(model.getIcon())){
                    return CommonUtility.RESTFUL_FOLDER;
                }
                return null;
            }

        });
        // Weight for column
        tableLayout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(50));


        // First column is for the component name
        col = createTableViewerColumn(HEADER, titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel model = (GenerateSkeletonComponentsStatusModel) element;
                return model.getComponentName();
            }
        });
        // Weight for column
        tableLayout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(100));

    }

    private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(Image image, String title, int bound, final int colNumber) {
        final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);
        final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
        column.setImage(image);
        column.setText(title);
        column.setWidth(bound);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setMoveable(true);
        column.setAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
        return viewerColumn;

    }
```

Comment: @greg-449: I want to display some text below or above the table viewer. Is there any way?

Comment: You just add multiple controls to the top level composite. That might include nested composites. You will probably need to use a different layout - GridLayout for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wizard page must only have one top level composite. You can add multiple controls (including nested composites) to that composite.

So for a label above to table:

```
top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
top.setLayout(new GridLayout());
setControl(top);

Label label = new Label(top, SWT.NONE);
label.setText("Some text to disply");
label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(top, .... flags
viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

Comment: Its still breaks. The scrolling disappears for the table viewer. I have attached the code snippet for the same.

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't attempt to put a label above the table - so what does it have to do with the answer?

Comment: You need to set the GridData on `tableComp`, the viewer control should not have GridData as TableColumnLayout deals with that. `tableComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));`

Comment: Then the `TableColumnLayout` and the call to `setColumnData` will be useless and my whole table will not be displayed. I have added the code in the question.

Comment: That is not the case. `tableComp.setLayoutData` sets layout data used by the parent composite of `tableComp`. The TableColumnLayout lays out the child of tableComp.

Comment: Now only the text appears. The table is gone as expected due to `TableColumnLayout`. Its obviously due to replacing `tableComp.setLayout(tableLayout)` with `tableComp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true))`

Comment: You need both of those.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks @greg.